# Parabolic Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjecture

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, modules

In this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277803/kazhdan-lusztig-theorem-for-composition-factors-of-verma-modules), Humphreys provides a reference concerning about Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjecture for arbitrary weights in $\mathfrak{h}^*$, which is under the name: **[Kashiwara and Tanisaki - Characters of irreducible modules with
non-critical highest weights over affine Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903123)**.

In other words, for complex semisimple Lie algebra, the problem for expressing $\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda)$ in terms of $\mathrm{ch}M(\mu)$ is completely answered, where $M(\eta)$ is the Verma module with weight $\eta$ and $L(\eta)$ is its unique simple quotient.

> What is about the problem for expressing $\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda)$ in terms of $\mathrm{ch}M_I(\mu)$, where $M_I(\eta)$ is the parabolic Verma module with weight $\eta$ and $L(\eta)$ is its unique simple quotient. Is it still a Conjecture or is it just easily derived from the expression of $\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda)$ in terms of $\mathrm{ch}M(\mu)$?

As [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/339250) by Rafael Mrđen, the above problem has been solved for arbitrary regular integral weights.

> I would like to know the story for **singular non-integral** weights. Is it the same formula? I believe there should be some difference as in the case for ordinary Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjecture. For example, one need the integral Weyl group of $\lambda$: $W_{[\lambda]}:=\langle s_\alpha\in W:\alpha\in \Phi_{[\lambda]}\rangle$, where $\Phi_{[\lambda]}:=\{\alpha\in\Phi:\langle\lambda,\alpha^\lor\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ in order to state the character formula of $L(\lambda)$ for non-integral $\lambda$. I also believe that singularity may play a role in the formula.
>
> I hope to see the explicit formula for $\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda)$ in terms of $\mathrm{ch}M_I(\mu)$ and some kinds of parabolic KL polynomials, where $\lambda$ is singular non-integral. Any paper talks about this explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See section 9.7. (Relative Kazhdan-Lusztig Theory) of his book [1], and the references therein.

---

[1] J. Humphreys. [Representations of semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG category $\mathscr O$](http://www.ams.org/books/gsm/094). Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 94. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2008.

Comment: What is the story for singular non-integral weights? Is it the same formula?

Comment: Take a look at Irving: Singular blocks of the category O, and Soergel: n-Cohomology of simple highest weight modules on walls and purity. They give a formula for expressing singular parabolic KL-polynomials to the regular parabolic ones.

Comment: I guess "his book" here means Humphreys's, but which one?  I first looked at the reflection groups book, but it has no Section 9.7.

Comment: @LSpice: edited.

Comment: Clickable:  Irving - Singular blocks of the category $\mathscr O$ [I](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02570868) [II](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/139/1197837); [Soergel - $\mathfrak n$-cohomology of simple highest weight modules on walls and purity](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01393837).